# Pandas: read head and middle of a file

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I just started with Pandas in Python and so far very good.

I have a big cvs file and I want to read only a portion of it. By the read_csv documentation ([link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)) there's the option `skiprows`, which says:

> skiprows : list-like or integer, default None
>
> Line numbers to skip (0-indexed) or number of lines to skip (int) at the start of the file

At first I thought that I could use this to read a 1st portion of my cvs file, process it, then read the 2nd portion and so on. But, when I read the 2nd portion, the headers are not there (because the header line was skipped).

I tried `header=0` but as the documentation states:

> header=0 denotes the first line of data rather than the first line of the file.

Then I saw that it's possible to read chunks of file. Sounds great, however the documentation is not that clear to me, so here are my questions:

1. For each chunk, does the line index continue from value of the previous chunk plus 1, or does it restart to zero?
2. Is the header set for each chunk?
3. Is it possible to use the `read_csv` command with the `skiprows` option, and still read the head in the first line of the file? (I could still open the file, read the first line and use it as header in the `names` option, but I don't really like this).

Comment: Check this [examples about chunking](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking) in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers:

1. It's restart to zero with each chunk
2. Yes
3. No

For question 3 you could use following, to keep the first row for header:

```
pd.read_csv('test.csv', skiprows=range(1, 10))
```

As @iled pointed out in the comment take a look to the example with chunks. Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

np.random.seed(10)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,5), columns=['a','b','c','d','e'])

In [29]: df1
Out[29]: 
          a         b         c         d         e
0  1.331587  0.715279 -1.545400 -0.008384  0.621336
1 -0.720086  0.265512  0.108549  0.004291 -0.174600
2  0.433026  1.203037 -0.965066  1.028274  0.228630
3  0.445138 -1.136602  0.135137  1.484537 -1.079805
4 -1.977728 -1.743372  0.266070  2.384967  1.123691
5  1.672622  0.099149  1.397996 -0.271248  0.613204
6 -0.267317 -0.549309  0.132708 -0.476142  1.308473
7  0.195013  0.400210 -0.337632  1.256472 -0.731970
8  0.660232 -0.350872 -0.939433 -0.489337 -0.804591
9 -0.212698 -0.339140  0.312170  0.565153 -0.147420

data = df1.to_string(index=False)
# In your case you don't need sep because you are reading the ordinarily csv file 
chunks = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+', chunksize=3)

In [40]: for chunk in chunks:
   ....:     print(chunk)
   ....:     
          a         b         c         d         e
0  1.331587  0.715279 -1.545400 -0.008384  0.621336
1 -0.720086  0.265512  0.108549  0.004291 -0.174600
2  0.433026  1.203037 -0.965066  1.028274  0.228630
          a         b         c         d         e
0  0.445138 -1.136602  0.135137  1.484537 -1.079805
1 -1.977728 -1.743372  0.266070  2.384967  1.123691
2  1.672622  0.099149  1.397996 -0.271248  0.613204
          a         b         c         d         e
0 -0.267317 -0.549309  0.132708 -0.476142  1.308473
1  0.195013  0.400210 -0.337632  1.256472 -0.731970
2  0.660232 -0.350872 -0.939433 -0.489337 -0.804591
          a        b        c         d        e
0 -0.212698 -0.33914  0.31217  0.565153 -0.14742
```

Comment: Thanks. I saw the example, but the explanation does make it explicit that the index restarts at 0 for each chunk. I would prefer to rely in a proper documentation rather than a example. The same goes for the header: the example it's not clear in saying that the headers (text columns) are the same for each chunk. In the example, it only shows numbered columns, which is not my case.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that you provided `columns` in the `DataFrame`. But still, the header is not the one in the file.

Comment: What do you mean that header is not the one in the file? Do you have multiple headers?

Comment: Sorry, the 'not' word should not be there.
What I wanted to point out is that you are providing the header as a parameter by using `columns=['a','b','c','d','e']`. But the header is always the first line of my file.

Comment: But in `data` it's first row. You could verify that from the above example with  `pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+', header=None)`

Comment: Now I got it!! Sorry for the confusion. I'll try in my solution and if works I'll accept your answer. Thanks! :)